# Are there any naming convention guidelines for REST APIs?

Tags: rest, naming-conventions

When creating REST APIs, are there any guidelines or defacto standards for naming conventions within the API (eg: URL endpoint path components, querystring parameters)?  Are camel caps the norm, or underscores? others?

For example:

```
api.service.com/helloWorld/userId/x
```

or

```
api.service.com/hello_world/user_id/x
```

Note: This is not a question of RESTful API design, rather the naming convention guidelines to use for the eventual path components and/or query string parameters used.

Any guidelines would be appreciated.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

I think you should avoid camel caps. The norm is to use lower case letters. I would also avoid underscores and use dashes instead

So your URL should look like this (ignoring the design issues as you requested :-))

```
api.service.com/hello-world/user-id/x
```

Comment: According to RFC2616 only the scheme and host portions of the URL are case-insensitive.  The rest of the URL, i.e. the path and the query SHOULD be case sensitive. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.3

Comment: Daniel, you are right, thanks for pointing that out. However, de-facto we usually expect urls to ignore cases, especially the  resource name part. It would make no sense for userid & UserId to behave differently (unless one of them returns 404)

Comment: @LiorH: Why do you think it "makes no sense" to be case-sensitive? Plenty of other contexts are case sensitive to good effect. There are some web services (e.g. Amazon S3) that *do* enforce case sensitivity for URL endpoints, and I think it's quite appropriate.

Comment: The original intention of URLs was to map directly to a server's file system. There hasn't been a case insenstive file system that was net accessible in probably 40 plus yeers, if ever. (DOS was not used to run servers - Don't go there)

Comment: @Dennis Windows server filesystems are case insensitive by default, unless I'm sorely mistaken http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725747.aspx

Comment: @samspot Good one! I thought that windows had gone straight to case sensitive file names when they created servers. WOW, they were still pushing THEIR way for as long as they could, i.e. "1 MicroSoft Way". ;-)

Comment: NTFS has been case-sensitive for a very long time now, but mounting it case-insensitive is the default.  In any case URLs definitely are case-sensitive and treating them otherwise is a serious misstep that will bite you some day.

Comment: What if the the user ID itself is case sensitive? e.g. api.service.com/hello-world/user-id/TheUsersCaseSensitiveId. Is it expected that any case-sensitive IDs should not be passed as URL parameters?

Comment: You say you *"would also avoid underscores"* but you do not give a reason for it?

Comment: @Dennis NTFS has always been a _case-remembering_ filesystem, not case-sensitive. Case-sensitivity for identifiers (in any platform) is silly: if you are distinguishing things exclusively by case, you've made a wrong turn. You'll still have to allow for the wrong turns of others (Postel's Law). Underscores are less convenient to type, and can be obscured by link underlines: https://api.example.com/hello_world/user_id/x

Answer (score 100):

The REST API for [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs), [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public), [Google Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview) and [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/) all uses underscores.

Comment: One of the side effects of that is that underscored 'words' are kept whole, together in google's search indexes. Hyhenated ones are broken into separate words.

Comment: Example: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

Comment: While the Google Maps API does uses underscores, the [Google Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jsoncstyleguide.xml?showone=Property_Name_Format#Property_Name_Format) requires Camel Case. The [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) and [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list), among others, use Camel Case.

Comment: Yet they still use '-' as the separator those urls :P
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list
https://developers.google.com/+/best-practices
https://dev.twitter.com/overview/case-studies

On the other hand they use camelCase in the query parameters.

Comment: I think I would use underscores after all discussion here and [there](http://blog.octo.com/en/design-a-rest-api/#case)

Comment: Nobody knows...

Comment: @Benjamin Aren't you confusing the URI with the content (json)?

Answer (score 85):

Look closely at URI's for ordinary web resources.  Those are your template.  Think of directory trees; use simple Linux-like file and directory names.

`HelloWorld` isn't a really good class of resources.  It doesn't appear to be a "thing".  It might be, but it isn't very noun-like.   A `greeting` is a thing.

`user-id` might be a noun that you're fetching.  It's doubtful, however, that the result of your request is only a user_id.  It's much more likely that the result of the request is a User.  Therefore, `user` is the noun you're fetching

```
www.example.com/greeting/user/x/
```

Makes sense to me.  Focus on making your REST request a kind of noun phrase -- a path through a hierarchy (or taxonomy, or directory).  Use the simplest nouns possible, avoiding noun phrases if possible.

Generally, compound noun phrases usually mean another step in your hierarchy.  So you don't have `/hello-world/user/` and `/hello-universe/user/`.  You have `/hello/world/user/` and `hello/universe/user/`.  Or possibly `/world/hello/user/` and `/universe/hello/user/`.

The point is to provide a navigation path among resources.

Comment: My question is more concerning the naming convention of the eventual pathnames and/or querystring parameters whatever they may be.  I agree with you design recommendations, so thank you, but with this question I'm just asking about naming conventions.

Comment: Just to note, there's nothing stopping you from using REST for non-hierarchical resources. The actual URI naming conventions you use are immaterial, just use whatever you think looks nice and is easy for you to parse on the server. The client shouldn't know anything about generating your URIs since you need to send the URIs to resources via hypertext in your responses.

Answer (score 31):

'UserId' is wholly the wrong approach. The Verb (HTTP Methods) and Noun approach is what [Roy Fielding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Fielding) meant for [The REST architecture](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm). The Nouns are either:

1. A *Collection* of things
2. A *thing*

One good naming convention is:

```
[POST or Create](To the *collection*)
sub.domain.tld/class_name.{media_type} 

[GET or Read](of *one* thing)
sub.domain.tld/class_name/id_value.{media_type}

[PUT or Update](of *one* thing)
sub.domain.tld/class_name/id_value.{media_type}

[DELETE](of *one* thing)
sub.domain.tld/class_name/id_value.{media_type}

[GET or Search](of a *collection*, FRIENDLY URL)
sub.domain.tld/class_name.{media_type}/{var}/{value}/{more-var-value-pairs}

[GET or Search](of a *collection*, Normal URL)
sub.domain.tld/class_name.{media_type}?var=value&more-var-value-pairs
```

Where {media_type} is one of: json, xml, rss, pdf, png, even html.

It is possible to distinguish the collection by adding an 's' at the end, like:

```
'users.json' *collection of things*
'user/id_value.json' *single thing*
```

But this means you have to keep track of where you have put the 's' and where you haven't. Plus half the planet (Asians for starters)
speaks languages without explicit plurals so the URL is less friendly to them.

Comment: What is meant with {var}? If I search for a user by name that would be for example .../user/username/tomsawyer ?

Comment: If you had three variables (var)s named x, y, z, then you're URL would look like: http://sub.domain.tld/x/value_of_x/y/value_of_y/z/value_of_z

Comment: @hstoerr Just to be sure I was clear, most script languages use some sort of 'curly bracket variable substitution'. So {var} signifies that some variable (it's name) resides there, and so the following {value} is where the value of the {var} before it. Example: sub.domain.tld/script/{var}/{value}.json [www.yelp.com/food_reviews/review_averages_higher_than/4.json ]would be trying to get the json results from yelp.com for food reveiws showing a value higher than 4.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion and kudos for thinking internationally.

Answer (score 14):

No. REST has nothing to do with URI naming conventions. If you include these conventions as part of your API, out-of-band, instead of only via hypertext, then your API is not RESTful.

For more information, see http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Comment: Give it a rest...it's still nice to have nice looking URLs.

Comment: Agree with @HDave, it's very much in the spirit of REST to have URLs which are easily comprehended. You're working with URLs, why wouldn't you want them to be as easily comprehended as the variable and parameter names in your code?

Comment: @mahemoff sorry, this is me being super pedantic. But what your URLs look like has nothing to do with REST. That does not mean that they're not a good thing to have, they're just orthogonal to what REST describes. It's misleading to say that REST is about structuring URLs this way, since it leads to people describing RPC APIs as REST just because they have readable / structured URLs.

Comment: In summary, nice looking URLs are great and everyone should have them. It has nothing to do with REST though.

Comment: @aehlke thanks for clearing this up. Rest isn't about URL structures. I don't understand why it's so hard for people to understand.

Comment: @user1431072 years of Rails etc. abusing the term "REST", unfortunately

Answer (score 9):

Domain names are not case sensitive but the rest of the URI certainly can be. It's a big mistake to assume URIs are not case sensitive.

Answer (score 5):

I have a list of guidelines at http://soaprobe.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/soa-rest-service-naming-guideline.html which we have used in prod.  Guidelines are always debatable... I think consistency is sometimes more important than getting things perfect (if there is such a thing).

Answer (score 4):

If you authenticate your clients with Oauth2 I think you will need underscore for at least two of your parameter names:

- client_id
- client_secret

I have used camelCase in my (not yet published) REST API. While writing the API documentation I have been thinking of changing everything to snake_case so I don't have to explain why the Oauth params are snake_case while other params are not.

See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the camel case is the issue in that example, but I imagine a more RESTful naming convention for the above example would be:

api.service.com/helloWorld/userId/x

rather then making userId a query parameter (which is perfectly legal) my example denotes that resource in, IMO, a more RESTful way.

Comment: This is not a question of RESTful API design, rather the naming convention guidelines to use for the eventual path components and/or query string parameters used.  In your example, should the path components be in camel caps as you have used, or underscores?

Comment: Well since in REST your URLs are your interfaces, then it is kind of an API question.  While I don't think there are any guidelines specific to your example, I would go with camel case personally.

Comment: You shouldn't use query parameters for resources that you want to be cached at any level of the HTTP stack.

Comment: @aehlke The exact opposite holds true as well. If you DON'T want query parameters cached, use the GET style for the parameters, ~OR~ make DARN SURE to modify / insert anti caching headers for anything that you don't want cached. Also, thre is some header that is a hash of the object/page returend, use that to indicate changes of things you DO want cached, but updated when there's edits.

Comment: @aehlke Found out about caching and am adding it. I remember a CodeCamp presentation where one of the speedups was doing all these headers, and then changing the file name and all references to it when it's contents changed in order to get borwsers and proxies to server a newer version after a long cache time had been set. Here is all the gory details: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it's preferable to use as few special characters as possible in REST URLs.  One of the benefits of REST is that it makes the "interface" for a service easy to read.  Camel case or Pascal case is probably good for the resource names (Users or users).  I don't think there are really any hard standards around REST.

Also, I think Gandalf is right, it's usually cleaner in REST to not use query string parameters, but instead create paths that define which resources you want to deal with.

http://api.example.com/HelloWorld/Users/12345/Order/3/etc