# I just cloned a repo and the first thing it says in Github is "Uncommitted changes"? Not CRLF related

Tags: github

Bear with me I'm completely new to Github but have experience with TortoiseSVN, diffs, adding, committing, etc.

So I just cloned https://github.com/faux123/Nexus_5/ want to poke around.

The first thing I notice looking at the clone on desktop is there are about 10 files with uncommitted changes that I did not make. New content, not just a different line endings...

Why is this, and how do I make it stop?

```
$ git status
# On branch kk_mr2
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_MARK.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_TTL.h
#       modified:   include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_HL.h
#       modified:   net/netfilter/xt_DSCP.c
#       modified:   net/netfilter/xt_HL.c
#       modified:   net/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.c
#       modified:   net/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.c
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

here's an example of one of the files, xt_CONNMARK.h

```
@@ -1,6 +1,31 @@
-#ifndef _XT_CONNMARK_H_target
-#define _XT_CONNMARK_H_target
+#ifndef _XT_CONNMARK_H
+#define _XT_CONNMARK_H

-#include <linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h>
+#include <linux/types.h>

-#endif /*_XT_CONNMARK_H_target*/
+/* Copyright (C) 2002,2004 MARA Systems AB <http://www.marasystems.com>
+* by Henrik Nordstrom <hno@marasystems.com>
+ *
+ * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
+ * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
+ * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
+ * (at your option) any later version.
+ */
+
+enum {
+   XT_CONNMARK_SET = 0,
+   XT_CONNMARK_SAVE,
+   XT_CONNMARK_RESTORE
+};
+
+struct xt_connmark_tginfo1 {
+   __u32 ctmark, ctmask, nfmask;
+   __u8 mode;
+};
+
+struct xt_connmark_mtinfo1 {
+   __u32 mark, mask;
+   __u8 invert;
+};
+
+#endif /*_XT_CONNMARK_H*/
```

Comment: How should we know? What is the output of `git status`? Of `git diff`?

Comment: modifications I didn't make, what else???

Comment: Can you show (at least a subset of) the diffs as well?

Comment: I think my git install is messed up. I closed github for windows, opened SmartGit pointed at the same clone on harddrive, discarded the changes (Github windows wouldn't let me for whatever reason) reverting to HEAD, and was fine. I opened github for windows again and it apparently reapplied these modifications.
This was happening before I uninstall/reinstalled. Going to try again.

Comment: cleaned the git install...it's something with the repo...zip file has duplicates of these files. What is this, why is it happening, and is it normal?
emailing git support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because a a filename case issue.

In [`include/linux/netfilter`](https://github.com/faux123/Nexus_5/tree/kk_mr2/include/linux/netfilter), [`xt_CONNMARK.h`](https://github.com/faux123/Nexus_5/blob/kk_mr2/include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h) exists also as [`xt_connmark.h`](https://github.com/faux123/Nexus_5/blob/kk_mr2/include/linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h), in the same folder.

Windows, as a case insensitive environment, doesn't know how to handle it: the last one override the first.

```
include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
include/linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h

include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h
include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ecn.h
```

It is likely that your [`core.ignorecase` config is set to `true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688308/6309), which makes git ignore the issue and override `xt_CONNMARK.h` with `xt_connmark.h`.

In other words, this repo isn't meant to be cloned on Windows.

Comment: Note: where there should be only one path (same file, two different folders with different case), Git Unite is interesting: http://www.woodcp.com/2013/01/git-unite-fix-case-sensitive-file-paths-on-windows/. But that isn't the case here: those files are meant to exist with two different cases in the same folder.

Comment: To see the problem, type `xt_CONNMARK.h` in https://github.com/faux123/Nexus_5/find/kk_mr2