# Codeigniter Rest Server denies just one request

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, codeigniter, rest

### TL;DR

I get a `404 (Not Found)` error on calling an API method (`api/auth/authenticated`~GET). I only get this on my live-server, not on local and not on any other methods.

## The Problem

I use Codeigniter with a Rest-Server library. I have a simple method `api/auth/authenticated`(GET) that returns true if the user is logged in and false if not. On the live-server this method gives me a `404 (Not Found)` error. Other calls to the same api class work, for example `api/auth/login`(POST) works and `api/auth/logout`(GET) works as well.

### so how is this possible?

I have tried to delete the .htaccess file, but that didn't work. It can't be a typo since it works locally. Maybe some setting in Apache? But then why do the other methods work just fine?

I would be grateful for any ideas and hints.

### my app

- CodeIgniter 3.0.3
- [CodeIgniter Rest Server](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)
- AngularJs 1.5 with ngResource for client-side

### my server env

- digital ocean droplet
- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 5.6.15
- Apache 2.4.7

Comment: Are you getting a codeigniter 404 error? Or an apache2 one?

Comment: is htaccess enabled on your server env?

Comment: Check if `index.php/controller/resource/parameter/format` uri is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worst problems are always the most stupid ones ...

There should be a list on my desk.

**1. Check for typos** *(very important but was not the problem here)*

Now if we are working on Windows or OSX and everything works fine and then some parts just don't work on Linux this one is very important:

**2. Check filenames for case-sensitivity problems (also check the GIT config)**

The Problem was still a bit harder to find. I use Git to push my `live-deploy`branch to my remote repository, which is then picked up by [Deploybot](http://deploybot.com) and uploaded to my server. Git doesn't care about case sensitivity on default and files will stay like they were first added forever. Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688308/1886244) i could just type one command to change it.

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```