# Rename A Folder on git origin

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I am using Gitlab for storing my repositories on remote.
I recently changed the case of 1 folder name inside my local repository using the following command

```
 git mv FolderName foldername
```

The problem that I am facing is that the name of folder is not getting changed on origin after pushing. 
What might the cause and solution for this.

Comment: Did you add it to the staging area before committing and pushing?

Comment: yes I had added the changes to staging area

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git

Comment: I tried doing that didnt work for me. and in my case its renaming  a file

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a smarter solution, but the simple way I've done this in the past with files (but I imagine it would work with a directory too) is to rename the file to something that differs by more than just the case, then rename it back with the correct casing, for example:

```
git mv FolderName FolderName2
git commit ...
git push ...
giv mv FolderName2 foldername
git commit ...
git push ...
```

Obviously it depends how careful you want to be with your git history - this creates some not-very-pretty commits that you'd probably prefer not to have, but if you don't mind that, it's a quick and easy solution.