# Why does the name of this folder in git not match up with how it exists on the filesystem?

Tags: php, git, directory, phpstorm

I have a git repository in which there is a folder named "Sms", but in the past, was "SMS". It shows up in every filesystem as "Sms", but when I modify a file in there, `git status` is showing it as "SMS", and PHPStorm's built in git functionality doesn't see the change at all.

Furthermore, I can't view the history of any of the files in that directory through PHPStorm's git GUI.
Any ideas?

Comment: @vascowhite Wish it were that easy - `ls` only shows Sms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment is case insensitive and hence this issue. 
Give this a shot
"git mv --force SMS Sms"

"Git has a configuration setting that tells it whether to be case sensitive or insensitive: core.ignorecase. To tell Git to be case-senstive, simply set this setting to false"

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

Reference: [How do I commit case-sensitive only filename changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git)

Comment: Got: `renaming 'SMS' failed: Invalid argument`

Comment: Per your edit: changing the configuration setting worked - PHPStorm now sees all of my changes correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably problem of windows, they are case insensitive.

you can either switch to linux or try cygwin and test the git in there.

Comment: I'm on OS X, not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There are instances where Git vision of a folder does not match its actual case.
This is documented in Git 2.23 (Q3 2019)

See [commit ed33bd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed33bd8f305fd62c87059aa227b99d2411e8eabc) (24 Jun 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bf8126f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf8126fff9cdab2583f1c8b274c0d29ebd000c26), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### t0001: fix on case-insensitive filesystems
>
> On a case-insensitive filesystem, such as HFS+ or NTFS, it is possible that the idea Bash has of the current directory differs in case from what Git thinks it is.
>   That's totally okay, though, and we should not expect otherwise.
>
> On Windows, for example, when you call:

```
cd C:\GIT-SDK-64
```

> in a PowerShell and **there exists a directory called `C:\git-sdk-64`, the
>   current directory will be reported in all upper-case**.
>   Even in a Bash that you might call from that PowerShell.
>
> Git, however, will have normalized this via `GetFinalPathByHandle()`, and the expectation in t0001 that the recorded `gitdir` will match what `pwd` says will be
>   violated.
>
> Let's address this by comparing these paths in a case-insensitive manner when `core.ignoreCase` is `true`.
>
> Reported by Jameson Miller.