# Clear git local cache

Tags: git

I have a Webstorm project that I was about to commit, but before pressing the commit button in the Git Windows GUI, I remembered that I don't want to commit my `.idea` folder content.

So I used the website that auto generates `.gitignores` for certain IDEs and added it to my `.gitignore` file.

All `.idea` files that are explicitly ignored are still showing up to commit, despite me removing and re-added the files in question.

I've also committed the gitignore file without any other files, and re-pasted my content, but it still is not ignoring the .idea files.

How do I tell Git to refresh or clear its cache?
I tried /cd ing into the directory in question, and typing

`git clean -n`

but no files show up.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

> All .idea files that are explicitly ignored are still showing up to commit

you have to remove them from the staging area

```
git rm --cached .idea
```

now you have to commit those changes and they will be ignored from this point on.
Once git start to track changes it will not "stop" tracking them even if they were added to the `.gitignore` file later on.

You **must** explicitly remove them and then commit your removal manually in order to fully ignore them.

---

### [image]

[image]

Comment: I never commit the files I'm trying to ignore, though.. This tells me `fatal: pathspec '.idea' did not match any files`

Comment: When you type git status do you see them? WebStorm might have added them for you if you marked the checkbox to auto add files

Comment: I have no idea but it seems the command you gave me worked, even though it returned a fatal error.... The files no longer show up to commit.

Comment: you might consider adding `-r` for recursive removing

Comment: For me i had to include ```-r``` like ```git rm --cached -r .idea```

Comment: For me `git rm -rf --cached .`

Answer (score 196):

When you think your git is messed up, you can use this command to do everything up-to-date.

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -am 'git cache cleared'
git push
```

Also to revert back last commit use this :

```
git reset HEAD^ --hard
```

Comment: Do not use git push if you do not want to push changes to the remote. However if you did, go to version control tab at the bottom of android studio, right click previous commit and choose "Reset current branch to here"

Comment: the reset part was at best confusing. but I did up to 'git push', and was fine.

Comment: A Warning on this answer.  The `git rm -r --cached .` followed by `git add .` will first reset all your project's files and the warning goes on `git add .` because you might be adding files that aren't ready to commit and push. Do a `git reset .` and then `git status` to check if all the files are ready to add, commit and push.

Answer (score 34):

if you do any changes on git ignore then you have to clear you git cache also

```
git rm -r --cached . 
git add . 
git commit -m 'git cache cleared'
git push
```

if want to remove any particular folder or file then

```
git rm  --cached filepath/foldername
```

Answer (score 10):

after that change in git-ignore file run this command , This command will remove all file cache not the files or changes

> git rm -r --cached .

after execution of this command commit the files

for removing single file or folder from cache use this command

> git rm  --cached filepath/foldername

Answer (score 7):

```
git rm --cached *.FileExtension
```

This must ignore all files from this extension

Answer (score 3):

To remove cached .idea/ directory.
e.g. `git rm -r --cached .idea`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with :

```
$ git clean -d -n
```

afterward it will show you what it will delete if that's what you want to do :

```
git clean -f -d
```

Answer (score -1):

**first**

```
(git clone <url repos>)
```

**second**

```
cut all files to another folder
```

### run these codes one by one

```
git rm --cached star.star (shift+8)

git add .

git commit -m "first commit"

git branch -M main

git remote add origin (url your repos)

git push -u origin main

then rpose cleared
```

---