# Gitignore deletes files when checking out to another branch

Tags: git, github

I am building a node.js project and I have a gh-pages branch for the github website. I have a mockoups folder in that branch that I've included in the .gitignore file, because I don't want it on github. Whenever I checkout to another branch the folder gets deleted.

How do I keep the folder but not commit it to github?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git is deleting an ignored file when i switch branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691618/git-is-deleting-an-ignored-file-when-i-switch-branches)

Answer (score 0):

If you have it in the .gitignore in the other branches I would suggest clearing cache
[Clear git local cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863484/clear-git-local-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Only untracked data is left untouched on checkout.

Make sure your folders were not already tacked when you added them to your `.gitignore`.

```
git rm --cached -r afolder/
```

Then try and checkout another branch.