# Git Ignore common directories in subprojects

Tags: git, gitignore

There are multiple git projects (using springboot) under one larger project.

```
ContainerProject
-.gitignore
  Subproj1/
   -.gitignore
   -target/ 
  Subproj2
   -.gitignore
   -target/ 
 ....
```

I need to ignore the target folder in all the projects within the `.gitignore` for the umbrella project.
I tried

```
**/target/
**/target
**/target/*
```

But none seems to be working for me. `git status` for the container project still lists changes from these target folders in the sub projects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this in your `.gitignore`:

```
target
```

It should work!

Example:

I've above entry (`target`) in the `.gitignore` in the following sample tree:

```
Test
- .gitignore
- abc
  - target/a.txt
  - xyz
    - target/a.txt
- test
  - target/a.txt
```

Using `git status` or from Git GUI, the `target` directory entries are not visible.

Comment: No it does not seem to.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan: Did you remove all the others? I just tested it and it worked.

Comment: Need to ignore all target folders of sub-projects. viz- `Subproject1/target/* and  Subproject2/target/*`

Comment: @RajeevRanjan: Yup. That's what I've just tested. I've added my example in my answer also. Kindly look at that also. You might need to remove any conflicting entries in the `.gitignore' files of sub projects.

Comment: Yes. Your answer very much describes what I wanted. But I think my issue is around git caching - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863484/clear-git-local-cache. Thanks

Comment: @RajeevRanjan: So, clearing your cache solved your issue? I wasn't thinking about the cache. :)