# Why Eclipse Git shows the red flag in synchronizing a file in 2 branches with no real difference?

Tags: eclipse, git

In Eclipse I compare 2 branches – the current branch and the release branch. There is no difference  between the current branch and the release branch for the file build.gradle, nevertheless synchronize shows the red flag. Why? And how to fix this?

The command

```
git diff current release build.gradle
```

shows no difference

[image]

Comment: Can you show the console output of running a git diff for that file? If you don't know how, it would look something like `git diff branch1 branch2 build.gradle`. This will tell you if there are really differences or if it is just an error on the extension of Eclipse.

Comment: Are you really sure there are no whitespace or encoding changes?

Comment: Drubio, please see the updated description

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After doing some research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48703146/6951294) helpful answer.

While in the appropriate directory, I executed `git rm -r --cached .` and reverted back the identified file without committing it. After that, I did the team synchronization in Eclipse and it wasn't showing any differences anymore.