# .gitignore will not ignore folders

Tags: github, version-control, gitignore

I am pulling my hair out over this, I have a .gitignore file I coded up in vscode to ignore a venv and a few other things and literally nothing works. It works fine for Background.mp4 and Music.mp4, but for the life of me, I can't seem to get it to ignore the rest. Would really appreciate some answers.

Also, just a side note, I do not run git on my computer. Instead, I use GitHub desktop, because I find it a ton less convoluted, if that affects the answers somehow

[image: .gitignore][image: github repo]

.__pycache__ is in a different folder but still will not be ignored)

Answer (score 3):

When You've once committed any file/folder and THEN you gitignore it, it won't work unless you clean up the cache. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863484/clear-git-local-cache/41863575) how to clean the cache. Try after removing the cache.

Comment: See, the thing is, I don't have git. Is there another way of doing that without git?