# can't push to the remote repository

Tags: git, github

I have a file in my project which size is over 100 Mb, I know that I can't push that file to the remote repository because github has limited the size of files, so I delete it in my local hard disk,After that I did  `git add` and `git remote -m 'I have deleted the big file'`.
Then I try to push my project to the remote repository, but I still failed this time. The hint is
`"error: File: 298db24d95135880d0f7b61f31fbe25c7e847e5a 101.55 MB, exceeds 100.00 MB`,
I swear to god I have deleted this file from my local hard disk.
How can I deal with this situation? I would be very grateful if someone told me the answer.

Comment: Tried to clear the cache? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863484/clear-git-local-cache

Comment: you probably have committed the file already and then deleted and committed once again. in that case the first commit contains your big file. you have to reset that first commit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Answer (score 0):

you can search for your file like the following to identify where it comes from:

```
git log --all --full-history -- <path-to-file>
```

that will give you the commits where file has been touched.

Comment: thank you so much , I just get a notice from stackflow. It says "Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one." and it's true. Anyway ,thank you very much for replying my question.