# Prevent commit of files with same names

Tags: linux, git, githooks

Assuming there's a Git repository hosted on a **Linux** machine and there are developers using both Windows and Linux, is there a way to prevent Linux developers from committing files with same names but different cases?

I think I've to write a server-side hook for this, but I don't know how to **validate** the names of incoming files inside the hook script.

Any help/references related to this would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688308/2872038

Comment: The problem is bigger than mere case-folding issues. For instance, a Linux user can create a file named `CON:` and store it in the repository, and Windows cannot handle that. Mac users sometimes store files with invalid-in-Windows characters in their names. Doing a really proper job of this is very difficult. But, if you just want to check case-folded names, consider using `git ls-tree -r` and piping it through `tr` in your script (assuming you are writing in shell).

Answer (score 0):

If you want keep some files locally then `git stash` is your friend. [stash usage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)