# How do I delete duplicate folder in Github?

Tags: github

I am having an issue with github duplicating a folder. I originally created all folders with a capital letter then changed it to lowercase. On my device it's all correct but in github the folders all have capitalized folder names and won't change when I push from my device. I don't know how to fix this.

Here's the repository I'm talking about.
https://github.com/haletothewood/ProjectEuler/tree/master/lib

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git