# GIT Change File extension

Tags: git

I am working on a post receive hook to stop commits if the file extension doesn't respect the naming convention (extension need to be in upperCase/ and necessarily .PSK or .PBK), the problem I am facing : when I change test.txt to test.PSK by

```
git mv -f test.txt test.PSK
git commit --amend
git push -u origin master
```

GIT doesn't recognize that the extension changed and the hook returns the same error. because  `git commit --amend` understand that test.txt is deleted  and that there's a new file test.PSK

Comment: What you try is not a really good idea ;) some systems don't recognize the case. So if you run that commands on windows or OSX it's possible that it's not working.

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: Don't change the file extension to uppercase what is in my eyes very useless. Lowercase make much more sense and it's not working on all systems. When you change the case on a linux system the Windows system won't recognize that and you get a lot of problems.

Comment: It's very important , it's a naming convention used to treat some issues from database

Comment: I don't know what you're trying but that doesn't sound like an application for git.

Comment: Don't change it in the hook. Just have your hooks check the convention and fail if it doesn't match. Pass the problem back to the developers to FIX THEIR CRAP if they aren't following the convention.

Comment: Wait, is the code shown your post-receive hook, or is an unspecified hook triggered by the `push` command in your question?

Comment: Git hooks should generally just fail with a message explaining why. You should really try to avoid *changing* the commit, because a dumb machine isn't going to handle exceptional cases well. Plus, by adding an extra commit, you've modified the history, which is just a pain for developers who now have re-merge from master before they can keep working. Believe me... after a few failed pushes, the devs will learn what to do/not do.

Comment: @JDB  I'm not handling that in my hook , the hook only stops the push. I'm just testing with the commands in the question and i found that when i change the extension nothing happens  . Guit doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @ILY - you're missing the `git add .`

Comment: @JBD OP is using `git mv` which stages the move, add is not needed.

Comment: More specifically, [this answer should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19956280/1615903)

Comment: @1615903 it's not the same I'm not having a problem with the filename but with the extension

Comment: File extension IS part of the filename.