# What is the reason of error on git push?

Tags: git, push, case-sensitive

I cloned remote repo from bitbucket.

i didn't do yet any changes and already have one file as changed:

```
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   www/src/app/locale/Test.csv

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

in fact its a symlink in the repo.

I tried to remove it and push this change then but get this error:

```
➜  git:(master) git push origin master                                                                   
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 535 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: One of your commit messages is missing an issue ID:
remote: 
remote:   0df2153: test
remote: 
remote: For more information, see https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/ZwjoE.
remote: 
To https://bitbucket.org/[replaced_url_path].git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://[replaced_url_path].git'
```

I noticed that in the remote repo Test.csv comes with the low registry in the name of file:
`www/src/app/locale/test.csv`

I tried to rename it and push it. The result the same - i cannot push it with the same error.

I tried to use git config option
`git config --system core.ignorecase false/true`

tried to do like here:
[How do I commit case-sensitive only filename changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git)

always result is the same.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It has nothing to do with case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the reason of error on git push?

The reason is contained in the response from the server:

> remote: One of your commit messages is missing an issue ID:

The remote repo requires that all commit messages must reference a corresponding entry in the bug tracker. Your commit message, however, is simply the word "test".

Comment: I read it, but i do not understand what git wants) what is the issue ID. Google says nothing about this. It would be more clearer if it sounds just smth like "your commit message is missing". Without "issue ID"

anyway thanks a lot for an idea! it helped me.

Comment: "I read it, but i do not understand what git wants" – Git doesn't want anything. The requirement comes from the owner of the repository, and the text of the error message either also comes from the owner of the repository, from the service they are using to implement this requirement, or from Bitbucket. By the way, I would be surprised if the owner of the repository allowed random people from the Internet to push to his repository anyway, I'm willing to bet that even if you supply an issue ID in the commit message, your push would be rejected with a different message. BTW: all of this is …

Comment: … explained in the "[For more information, see https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/ZwjoE.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/ZwjoE)" link in the error message.

Comment: one year ago it worked with "init" in the commit. Now i can push without ID but i need to write more words. I tried to push with "test update" and it did not work. After that i tried to add "update fix" and it works. What is the difference here? If ID must be there and its a strict rule according to the link so why smth like "update fix" or "init" works? (actually that was a reason why i did not think on ID)

Comment: You will have to ask the owner of the repository how he configured it and what kinds of commit messages he allows.