# How do I fix a "There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing" warning?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

Im building a simple signIn and signUp app, but i ran into a problem. My terminal in VScode is giving me several warnings stating that ""There are multiple models with name that only differ is casing.

I have checked the files that i edited but i am unable to find the problem. Anyone here who could direct me towards a proper solution?

So all i tried was just to look if i cant find any of these modules that differ only in casing, but i had no luck. Is there a possible way to find these words?

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/Forms/fesm2015/forms.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ
in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on
a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\tprat\Desktop\Youmaven\node_modules\@angular\Forms\fesm2015\forms.js
    Used by 5 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\tprat\Desktop\Youmaven\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!C:\Users\tprat\Desktop\Youmaven\src\app\shared\shared.module.ts* C:\Users\tprat\Desktop\Youmaven\node_modules\@angular\forms\fesm2015\forms.js    Used by 7 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\tprat\Desktop\Youmaven\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!C:\Users\tprat\Desktop\Youmaven\src\app\auth\signin\signin.component.ts
```

I expect this to just run with no error and spit a sign in works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534267/webpack-there-are-multiple-modules-with-names-that-only-differ-in-casing-but

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your own post, these two modules have the same file name. You need to fix this imports references so that they are the same.

```
C:\Users\tprat\Desktop\Youmaven\node_modules@angular\Forms\fesm2015\forms.js Used by 5 module(s)
C:\Users\tprat\Desktop\Youmaven\node_modules@angular\forms\fesm2015\forms.js Used by 7 module(s)
```

This means that you probably have:

```
import @angular/forms/..
import @angular/Forms/..
```

in various modules.

Comment: Do you mean inside those files that you are referring to? 
Im a bit lost in this issue, could you possible be so kind to navigate me through what i should do in a little bit more detail?

Comment: Look at the paths to those files. You have `Forms` and `forms`. Check your imports and make sure that you are not mixing case when you import the forms.

Comment: Cheers for the help broski ;) Found it, but it wasnt inside of the file destination that the console was pointing out.