# Should I care for warning from React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Everytime I run app, cmd always show this warning:

[image]

Overview, your app still operate normally, however I preparing to deploy app to client, is it risky?, if it is, how to fix it? Thanks your interest!

Comment: Usually I like to remove each warnings, they show something could cause further issues. In your case, you can misspell a module name because they are differing in casing only, that's a possible one. Probably [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534267/webpack-there-are-multiple-modules-with-names-that-only-differ-in-casing-but) helps.

Comment: try to change the name to be different, not only in `letter cases` but in `letters` itself

Comment: Yes, almost every old programmer has mysophobia, we cannot tolerate any warning, which is a good habit. ;)