# Importing axios results in a casing unexpected behaviour warning in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm going through a tutorial that makes use of [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for HTTP requests. I have set up an axios instance to look like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseUrl: 'https://www.google.com/'
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

I have saved it in the root of my project in a file called AxiosOrders.js. When I import the file using `import MyAxios from '../../AxiosOrders';` and do nothing else the console logs:

```
C:/DEV/Projects/learning-initiative/burger-builder/node_modules/process/browser.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\DEV\Projects\learning-initiative\burger-builder\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\DEV\Projects\learning-initiative\burger-builder\node_modules\process\browser.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\DEV\Projects\learning-initiative\burger-builder\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\DEV\Projects\learning-initiative\burger-builder\node_modules\react-error-overlay\lib\index.js
* C:\DEV\Projects\learning-initiative\burger-builder\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\dev\Projects\learning-initiative\burger-builder\node_modules\process\browser.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\DEV\Projects\learning-initiative\burger-builder\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\dev\Projects\learning-initiative\burger-builder\node_modules\axios\lib\defaults.js
```

When I use the imported object, it does not take the baseUrl from the instance I created.

```
MyAxios.post('/orders.json', order)
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Actually makes a request to `http://localhost:3000/orders.json`. When I place a debugger and try to print the object to the console by typing `MyAxios` it tells me `Uncaught ReferenceError: MyAxios is not defined`.

Is this what the casing warning is referring to or am I missing something?

My package.json as requested:

```
{
  "name": "burger-builder",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show how did you import axios instance. Also your package.json file. May be you have installed same library of different versions.

Comment: are you exporting the instance?

Comment: @Piyush I have added my package.json. Also, Ludwiguer, I am yes, sorry I missed it in the formatting above.

Comment: Can you share your directory structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the two modules are actually the same module: `node_modules\process\browser.js`

Anyway their complete name are `C:\DEV\...` and `C:\dev\...`; probably this is the cause of the warning; deleting `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` file and installing dependencies once again, should solve the problem of the warning.

Typing `MyAxios` in your console results in a `ReferenceError` because it's defined in your package and not a `window` attribute.

Once said that I think the source of your main problem (calling `http://localhost:3000/orders.json`) is somewhere else.

Hope this somehow helps.

Comment: Deleting `node_modules` did fix the casing warning and you were also correct that the source of my main problem was elsewhere. It turns out it should have been `baseURL` instead of `baseUrl`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below to solve your issue:

1. First, del your `node_modules` folder. Kill all your terminals(or windows cmd) and freshly open the terminal and navigate to your project path properly. **Make sure** to use correct case of your folder name. Eg: if your folder name is `DEV` don't do `cd dev`. Do `cd DEV`. Then do npm install. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53901224/13207394) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3609#issuecomment-352168847)
2. In your project, see if you are doing any `import React from 'React';` instead of `import React from 'react';`

There is nothing wrong in the way you are exporting and importing axios. If your path issue is resolved then the correct instance of the axios will be picked up and correct url will be picked up when you do `MyAxios.post`.

Comment: if answer doesn't help, plz share your github repo link and/or share more info as mentioned by other experts in the question's comment section.