# There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing (ReactJS, Babel, styled components)

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm currently learning react and I'm trying to used styled components but the moment I import them (`import styled from 'styled-components';`) live server gives me a warning - **There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.**

With this error log

```
C:\face-recognition-app\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!
C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\Personal Projects\face-recognition-app\node_modules\react-error-overlay\lib\index.js
C:\\face-recognition-app\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!
C:\Users\Korisnik\desktop\personal projects\face-recognition-app\node_modules\process\browser.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.

C:\\face-recognition-app\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!
C:\\face-recognition-app\node_modules\styled-components\dist\styled-components.browser.esm.js
```

Also, everything seems to be working fine bar that error log, I can style using styled. and it displays changes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534267/webpack-there-are-multiple-modules-with-names-that-only-differ-in-casing-but

Comment: I've been looking at my import code but can't seem to figure it out 

In Navigation.js I only use -
    `import React from 'react';
    import styled from 'styled-components';`

and in App.js I've got

    `import React from 'react'; 
    import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
    import './App.css';`