# localhost:3000 shows internal server error

Tags: node.js, frontity

I am new at using node.js and i am trying this new react framework called frontity for wordpress. Everything went great at first and "npx frontity dev" command worked fine and i was able to access the "localhost:3000" then while pointing my wordpress site i thought i messed up details and i didn't know the default ones. So i deleted the directory that was created by Node.js using "npx frontity create my-app". Then i uninstalled node.js and tried same again. Now this time when i used "npx frontity dev" it displayed internal server error.  So i deleted the [Displayed Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRSMK.jpg)directory again and uninstalled and re installed node.js multiple times. Now when i try using "npx frontity dev" command it displays the error shown in images with keywords "  WARNING in C:/my-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/defineProperty.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing." Help me, i am unable to find a solution to this.

Comment: seems like a caching issue. Try running `npm cache verify` and then try to set up a frontity project

Comment: It Displays: "Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache):
Content verified: 1447 (45668038 bytes)
Index entries: 2219
Finished in 3.15s"

Comment: try to remove this file node_module and the yarn .lock package.lock and try to install again

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53901224