# Multiple modules with names that only differ in casing when following guide

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-amplify

Trying to setup a basic react project with AWS amplify using the following guide:[AWS Setup](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/react#initialize-a-new-backend)

At the very bottom it tells you to copy and paste the following code below the last import in your index file.

```
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import awsExports from "./aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(awsExports);
```

Doing so makes my react project go form no errors to the following:

```
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Documents\Code\etutorr\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!D:\Documents\Code\eTutorr\node_modules\webpack\buildin\module.js
    Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Documents\Code\etutorr\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!D:\Documents\Code\eTutorr\node_modules\lodash\_nodeUtil.js
* D:\Documents\Code\etutorr\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!D:\Documents\Code\etutorr\node_modules\webpack\buildin\module.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Documents\Code\etutorr\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!D:\Documents\Code\etutorr\node_modules\node-libs-browser\node_modules\punycode\punycode.js
```

I've looked around on the for a solution but most I find online tell me to check my import casing but since I took it straight from the documentation I'm assuming its right.

Have tried deleting node_modules then running npm install.

Comment: Funny that it's now 4+ years later and it's still an issue, looking it up right now, no clue yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack: "there are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing" but modules referenced are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534267/webpack-there-are-multiple-modules-with-names-that-only-differ-in-casing-but)

Answer (score -1):

changing the root folder name to small letters will work.

for eg: rename Document folder to "document" and Code to "code"