# React - There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and every time i create a project using npx create-react-app I always have this warning

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack: "there are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing" but modules referenced are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534267/webpack-there-are-multiple-modules-with-names-that-only-differ-in-casing-but)