# WordPress and React - Fronitity framework Internal Server Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, wordpress, compiler-errors, npx

I tried this framework called Frontity. For the first try (run) everything was good, I had my demo page, and it worked well. I follow [these instructions](https://docs.frontity.org/getting-started/quick-start-guide).

For the second compile I got these error, and a lot: There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.

Only change what I have done was this one (connecting my frontity to my WordPress): https://docs.frontity.org/getting-started/connecting-to-wordpress

(Again: for the first run, it was good.)
Nothing, literally nothing was changed, I do not even started any other software :)

After all this, I deleted everything, moved to another folder, started over the whole thing and for now I only get the same errors, and an Internal Server Error in my browser.

I have this issue with or without running the xampp server.

Any idea what went wrong?

Localhost WordPress (xampp), localhost:3000 Frontity (default), Windows 10, Chrome browser.

[errors after compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhWA2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here in the console output:

[image]

I'm not sure at which point those files with differing cases are
generated, but I think the following should fix your issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53901224/2638310

> Ensure that the path you used in your terminal has the correct
> capitalization. For example if you're using git bash on Windows and
> your project has the following path:
>
> C:\MyProjects\project-X
>
> If you access it using cd /c/myprojects/project-x (note the lack of
> capital cases) and then run npm start you might face this problem.
>
> The solution would be to consider the project path case-sensitive and
> use it as follows:
>
> cd /C/MyProjects/project-X

Comment: Thank you. This was my problem.
Sidenote: the drive letter (C) is not capital in the Total Commander path line/bar (ctrl+c) and it is not capital in the command line there.