# How to change casing of a file that in under version control in Team Services Online?

Tags: tfs

To change the casing of a file name under Git we can use `git mv` command as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git).

How do we achieve the same result in TFS?

We have a large collection of team projects (more than 150 team projects) and each team project is broken down into 6 Visual Studio projects at least, that makes at least 900 Visual Studio projects. Now in some of them we have `Web.config` file and in some of them `web.config` file. The point is, we're creating some automated QA/QC tools that need a consistent casing across our projects.

We want to change the lowercase `web.config` to PascalCased `Web.config` in all files.

We change file names on Windows, but TFS doesn't recognize it as change. We use `Source Control Explorer` to rename files there, and still it doesn't recognize the change.

We used `tf rename web.config Web.config` and it complains that the file already exists. We're stuck at this point. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the `web.config`  files are in source control? Did you exclude them in the `.tfignore` or `.gitignore` file?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the files are really in source control which are not prevented tracking by your settings (`.gitignore` or `.tfignore` ).

Try to **get latest** first (In `Source Control Explorer` right click the project node --> **Get Latest Version** ). Then rename the files. I tested on my side and the rename from lowercase `web.config` to Uppercase `Web.config` works as expected.

If that still not work, you can try to remap the workspace or create a new workspace to check that again.

Besides, you can also try to rename the file from web portal.

[image]

Comment: @mohammad rostami siahgeli Have you resolved the issue? Is that helpful for you? any update?