# TS1261: Already included file name 'xxx' differs from file name 'xxx' only in casing

Tags: typescript, macos

I have the `/app/client/modules/activity/pages/New/hooks.ts` file in my project. As you can see the folder is `New`, and the first letter is uppercase.

When I run the webpack build command, got below error:

```bash
ERROR in /root/app/client/modules/activity/pages/new/index.tsx
ERROR in /root/app/client/modules/activity/pages/new/index.tsx(5,45):
TS1261: Already included file name '/root/app/client/modules/activity/pages/new/hooks.ts' differs from file name '/root/app/client/modules/activity/pages/New/hooks.ts' only in casing.
  The file is in the program because:
    Imported via './hooks' from file '/root/app/client/modules/activity/pages/new/index.tsx'
    Root file specified for compilation
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
}
```

- OS: macOS
- Disk info:

```bash
File System Personality:   APFS
Type (Bundle):             apfs
Name (User Visible):       APFS
```

I had read this question ['File name differs from already included file name only in casing' on relative path with same casing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197940/file-name-differs-from-already-included-file-name-only-in-casing-on-relative-p)

I want to keep the `forceConsistentCasingInFileNames` configuration be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

example:  message and Message - the words have a difference in only one letter, one is uppercase, the other is not.

you need : messageStyle and Message - more differents

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).