# Problem building ionic app when filename has changed case

Tags: github, ionic-framework

This is my first Ionic build - to begin with, I used the sample build which worked fine. I then imported some of my existing components to the project; at some point after making a GitHub commit/push, I had an lint error because of incorrect case on filenames with Vue components.
I have now corrected those; there are no longer any lint errors and the build works without errors in VS Code. But when I push the revised files to GitHub and then run the build from the Ionic appflow dashboard, I am getting errors (one for each of three filenames concerned):

```
src/views/Tab1Page.vue(16,23): error TS1261: Already included file name '/builds/quilkin/wordwheel-wt6t64/src/views/wordwheel/wordWheel.vue.ts' differs from file name '/builds/quilkin/wordwheel-wt6t64/src/views/wordwheel/wordwheel.vue.ts' only in casing.
  The file is in the program because:
    Imported via './wordwheel/wordWheel.vue' from file '/builds/quilkin/wordwheel-wt6t64/src/views/Tab1Page.vue.ts'
    Matched by include pattern 'src/**/*.ts' in '/builds/quilkin/wordwheel-wt6t64/tsconfig.json'
```

so, in summary, I changed three filenames from e.g. `camelcase.vue` to `camelCase.vue` and each is giving errors; the old filenames appear to be 'stuck' in my github repo.
So, how to proceed? Since I don't need any history for this project (yet), maybe I should just abandon this repo and start again?

Comment: Rename the file to camelCaseB.vue and test or clear the build files,  (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197940/file-name-differs-from-already-included-file-name-only-in-casing-on-relative-p (2) https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-clean-build/64892/4

Comment: Ok, I just renamed the files and all OK. So it appears that the problem is with VS Code, it doesn't mark the changed case as significantly different. VSCode/Windows should realise that files on GitHub may be used by other OS's where flename cases matter!

Comment: Windows OS is case preserve but case insenstiive. Anyway you can now rename it back and it should work with the original file name you wanted