# git move folder only by case sensitive name change

Tags: git, git-commit, case-sensitive, mv, git-config

I have a folder in git (on FS) called

```
fooBar
```

however, in git it is registered twice:

`foobar` and `fooBar`

so a [How do I commit case-sensitive only filename changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git)

```
git mv -f foobar fooBar
```

fails with:

```
fatal: Umbenennung von 'foobar' fehlgeschlagen: Invalid argument
```

How can I synchronise it again i.e. only have a single  reference to the FS object with name `fooBar`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19956280/7976758

Comment: thanks. this is the solution