# solving the problem of my git-hub regarding not recognizing case sensitive issues

Tags: git, github, case-sensitive

I have a GitHub, two directory is made by names

Notebooks and notebooks

when I push something it goes to folder Notebooks which is not desired (it works before without problem)

now, I just put my file by upload in the interface in GitHub! copy paster new file to correct folder in my local machine..which is very stupid! since I did not make the GitHub, It is for my professor, I am working in this way, can you let me know what should I do?

I saw this would be a solution, but I am afraid to use it

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

Comment: Can you mention what OS and version of Git you're using?

Comment: thank you for your response, Windows 10, I tool look for the version of git, could not find..probably the last version

Comment: @bk2204    thank you for your response, Windows 10, I took look for the version of git, could not find..probably the last version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I commit case-sensitive only filename changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git)