# How to make git track file/folder name case changes?

Tags: git

So here's the issue :

I use git for a repo in *windows*. Renamed some assets folder and files to **lowercase** but git didn't track the changes. Resulting in an inconsistent repo in other devices.

How to make git track file/folder name **case** changes so that it syncs across locations (different OSs too) consistently?

**EDIT**: I notice before asking that it might a duplicate question but I was looking for a different solution rather than `git mv`

**UPDATE:** So `git config core.ignorecase false` - this seems to be more convenient in that case because you don't have to run `git mv` every time you've to rename something. Original answer to can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688308/10843897)

Comment: Clarification: So you renamed some asset folders and files but Git says everything is up to date or that the changed files aren't added to Git or what?

Comment: Yes @Divergence

Comment: No @FoezAhmed which one: 1. Git says everything is up to date or 2. the changed files aren't added to git

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you at first.

Git says everything is up to date.

@Divergence

Comment: I assume you are running on a case-insensitive file system?

Comment: Yes, Windows @Divergence

Answer (score 3):

If you have a directory named `Assets` and you want to rename it to `assets`, run `git mv Assets assets`, and then commit that change. That will tell Git that you want the files in the directory renamed, since on a case-insensitive system, Git has no way of knowing that you've changed the case unless you tell it.

If you want to see what case Git is storing your names in, you can use `git ls-files` to do so: that will list all the files that are tracked.