# Changing capitalization of file extensions in Git

Tags: git, git-bash

I have a use case like where I have image name extension with capital letters like **image.PNG**, but in my code I have image.png, I want to change to the **image.png ,** (assume I don't want to change in my code) when I am **changing the file name in folder but it is not showing in the modified files to commit**.

**OS: Windows 10**
**git version 2.18.0.windows.1**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I commit case-sensitive only filename changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rename+file+different+case

Answer (score 14):

Try to use the command `git mv <old_filename> <new_filename>` which is a shorthand for the removal of the old file and the addition of the new one, which will show the change in the name case in the index. [(Source)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv)