# Deployed to Azure: Fixing the Mime Type sends an empty css file to the server

Tags: css, asp.net-core, static-files

Everything is working fine locally. But when deployed to Azure, loading the css shows this error:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain
```

It happens in all the browsers.

The application loads a spa in react.

These are the middlewares I am using in this order.

```
if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();            
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error", "?statusCode={0}");
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseOurCustomAuthenticate();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "api",
                template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```

The custom authenticate middleware that we are using checks if the path starts with "/styles" it will not do anything and let it load.

This is the cshtml file where I include the css file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/notFound.css">
</head>
<body class="body-content">
```

This is where the styles and images are

[image]

The image is being loaded properly on the server, only the style have this problem.

So in my custom middleware I did this:

```
if (httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/styles"))
{
     httpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
}
```

Now the content-type is correct in the network tab, but the style is not still loading. When I click on the css file it is an empty file.

I have read a lot of posts regarding this issue, but couldn't still solve it.

Comment: I'm curious what would happen if you call your custom authentication middleware before `app.UseStaticFiles()`.

Comment: Is the stylesheet actually deployed? Does it exist in Azure?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I commented out the custom middleware, and deployed. Still no change. I don't think that middleware is the problem.

Comment: @Morpheus I pulled the container to my local, looked at the content. The folder was Style with capital "S" not small "s". I have renamed that while ago and it was correct in my local, but looking at the code on the source control server, I saw that git didn't reflect that change, because apparently git is case-insensitive. So I update that on the source control server directly and it fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Great that you found the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

At this point I had to see if the stylesheet is actually deployed.

To do so, I pulled the contianer and run it locally to see what files are copied there.

I found that the styleSheet is copied under a folder "Styles" with capital "S" instead of "styles" with small "s". We use git for our source control and git didn't catch the rename I made to this folder.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git) is how to commit such a change with git case sensitive. Renaming the folder properly fixed the problem for me.