# header.css file not importing

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby

I have been creating a site on my IDE and it has been working perfectly. But I ran into problems when deploying to Netlify. After changing all my file names to lowercase, now my 'header.css' file is not importing into header.js. I have checked the file path and it is correct. Can anyone please help me?

https://github.com/genesis16/alphaomega

1. changed file names to lowercase.
2. changed npm versions
3. installed css loader
4. changed file path to './components/header.css'

> import './header.css' import '..components/header.css'
>
> warning  in ./src/components/Card.js ⠀ There are multiple modules with
>   names that only differ in casing. This can lead to unexpected behavior
>   when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.

I have saved the file as `card.js` to pass Netlify's casing requirements. But it is still showing in my error log with capital `Card.js`.

I expected to run Gatsby develop and have my site load up properly with the `header.css` file imported.

Comment: This can be a git problem, git will not pick up case only changes to your filename unless you tell it so. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git

Comment: Yes but shouldnt it still work on my local dev environment?