# Heroku Ruby Application Error(Missing helper file helpers?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

This is what my console says

```
         8: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
         7: from /app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<main>'
         6: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.1/lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb:19:in `inherited'
         5: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:108:in `helper'
         4: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:94:in `modules_for_helpers'
         3: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `modules_for_helpers'
         2: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `map!'
         1: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:148:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:151:in `rescue in block in modules_for_helpers': Missing helper file helpers/items_helper.rb (AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError)
```

thanks in advance

--------Edit----------

I found out what the problem was. For some reason, whenever I push to heroku my items_helper.rb becomes Items_helper.rb. Anyone knows why or how  I can solve this?

Comment: remove some code in gemfile because stackoverflow do not allow too much code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds a lot like the filename case is different in Git than it is in your OS, try out the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20907647/1544440) and see if it helps you out:

```
git mv -f Items_helper.rb items_helper.rb
```

and then commit and push and try again.

Microsoft has a [great article on Git case sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/case-sensitivity?view=azure-devops) and how macOS and Windows filesystems work that's worth a read.

Comment: Yes, this helped. For others facing the same problem, I was on a mac.