# How to fix Next.js Vercel deployment module not found error

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, vercel

My next.js app works on my machine and was working when deployed on Vercel but now it fails when building on Vercel with the following error:

I've tried deleting node_modules and running `npm install` a few times but with no joy.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you!

> Running "npm run build"
>   20:43:24.926
>   tdwcks@1.0.0 build /vercel/5ccaedc9
>   20:43:24.926
>   next build
>   20:43:24.967
>   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
>   20:43:24.967
>     throw err;
>   20:43:24.967
>     ^
>   20:43:24.967
>   Error: Cannot find module '../build/output/log'
>   20:43:24.967
>   Require stack:
>   20:43:24.967
>   - /vercel/5ccaedc9/node_modules/.bin/next
>   20:43:24.967
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
>   20:43:24.967
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
>   20:43:24.967
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
>   20:43:24.967
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
>   20:43:24.967
>       at Object. (/vercel/5ccaedc9/node_modules/.bin/next:2:46)
>   20:43:24.967
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
>   20:43:24.967
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
>   20:43:24.967
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
>   20:43:24.967
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
>   20:43:24.967
>       at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
>   20:43:24.967
>     code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>   20:43:24.967
>     requireStack: [ '/vercel/5ccaedc9/node_modules/.bin/next' ]
>   20:43:24.967
>   }
>   20:43:24.969
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   20:43:24.969
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   20:43:24.970
>   npm ERR! tdwcks@1.0.0 build: `next build`
>   20:43:24.970
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   20:43:24.970
>   npm ERR! 
>   20:43:24.970
>   npm ERR! Failed at the tdwcks@1.0.0 build script.
>   20:43:24.970
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>   20:43:24.974
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   20:43:24.974
>   npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2020-06-17T19_43_24_971Z-debug.log
>   20:43:24.979
>   Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
>   20:43:25.342
>   [dmesg] follows:
>   20:43:25.342
>   [  962.449223] ecs-bridge: port 1(veth2a021300) entered disabled state
>   20:43:25.342
>   [  962.453655] device veth2a021300 entered promiscuous mode
>   20:43:25.342
>   [  962.457686] ecs-bridge: port 1(veth2a021300) entered blocking state
>   20:43:25.342
>   [  962.462004] ecs-bridge: port 1(veth2a021300) entered forwarding state
>   20:43:26.242
>   Done with "package.json"

Here's my Package.json

```
{
  "name": "tdwcks",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cjs": "0.0.11",
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.2",
    "framer-motion": "^1.11.0",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.2",
    "next": "^9.4.4",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-ga": "^3.0.0",
    "react-markdown": "^4.3.1",
    "react-player": "^2.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.4.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: So you can successfully build on your local machine with `npm run build`?

Comment: Yeah, building on my local machine totally fine.

Comment: Do you use a .gitignore file ? If yes, what's in it ?

Comment: @tenclea Nope I don't.

Comment: Have you tried to use another version of the `next` module ?

Comment: Yeah, still didn't run on Vercel.

Comment: This line seems interesting `npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || (...) || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. 21:31:01.088` even though it's only a warning. You should try to give `npm i typescript` a shot

Comment: Having the same issue as of now. Seems to have come out of nowhere. Been building and deploying the same Dockerfile for months, and suddenly it starts to fail with this error.

Comment: Did you find out what it was? I now have this bug as well.

Comment: I've asked for help here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14897

Comment: You can reach out to our support channel on https://vercel.com/support/request if you have a reproduction. We will happily take a look at all cases.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This error typically happens if you're accidentally committing `node_modules` to your project's Git Repostiory.

Could you try to do the following?

1. Ensure all changes have been committed and you have a clean directory.
2. Run `rm -rf node_modules` (or delete the folder on Windows).
3. Run `git add -A` then `git commit -m "Remove all module files"`.
4. Add `node_modules` to your `.gitignore` file (and save).
5. Run `git add -A` then `git commit -m "Update ignored files"`.
6. Verify your directory is completely clean via `git status`.
7. Then, run `git push`. This deployment should work on Vercel.
8. Finally, re-run `npm i` or `yarn` depending on your package manager to get your local copy working.

Comment: This is the answer, I found tons of question about this problems, and for me in this case it's works, only with the step 1 works for me, thanks!.

Comment: Did all that and it said, 'nothing to commit'.

Answer (score 54):

This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541435/3051080

TL;DR; update `git cache`:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add --all .
git commit -a -m "Versioning untracked files"
git push origin master
```

Comment: This is what worked for me. 
Due to changing letter case of a folder in components folder.
The cache didn't track it, meaning it was pushing the old version.

Comment: Note that you might be able to do `git config core.ignorecase false` which will then show files with changed cases for you to re-commit

Comment: This worked for me. Also changed the folder from capitalized to lowercase

Comment: This is gold! I remember I renamed two folders. Funny thing is, the new name  is what I have on my remote repo, but still it didn't work till I ran this command. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 26):

I had to edit my `package.json` to use the `next` binary that ships in the `node_modules/next` directory:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node_modules/next/dist/bin/next start -p $PORT"
}
```

Not the most elegant fix but it works.

Comment: This is the only thing that actually works for me.. But why does NextJS expect the node_modules in a production deployment where we already ran the export command.. This is mind-boggling

Comment: Where are you deploying your code? I've had success using environment variables in Microsoft Azure: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14897#discussioncomment-86108

Comment: It's deployed to Azure DevOps (private repo) and picked by a custom pipeline. Works fine now, using your updated `package.json` line for `yarn start`.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me too. Is there something messed up locally that it doesn't look in node_modules for package.json commands?

Comment: when i do this and try to run my dockerfile, it keeps telling me to give port argument though i give it with "docker run -p 80:3000 my-app"

Answer (score 11):

I'm having this exact same issue. I think it may be an internal issue with Vercel's deployment infrastructure. Notice the line it is failing on:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../build/output/log' 20:43:24.967
Require stack: 20:43:24.967
- /vercel/5ccaedc9/node_modules/.bin/next 20:43:24.967
```

My issue started yesterday, quite unexpectedly -- i.e. with a very simple commit. In my case, previously successful deploys also fail. Likewise, deleting the project and starting over did not help. I am in communication with Vercel support but they have not yet acknowledged the problem is on their end yet or offered any kind of solution.

Comment: That's interesting I'll get on to their support too.

Comment: I received a rather dubious but successful response from them. Is node_modules part of your repo? If so, try deleting it. Not sure why this would suddenly become a deployment issue, as I've made several hundred success deploys with this project previously. Nevertheless, whatever issue they were having seems to be fixed on my end by removing node_modules from the repo itself (also .next/, in case you had that there as well)

Comment: Hello,

If you are facing problems with Vercel, message us at https://vercel.com/support/request w/ a reproduction so we can assist you.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. In my github desktop I noticed that a file that was capitalized in the editor was not in the github desktop. Fixed the spelling to match what was showing on github and the project built successfully.

Comment: Yeah for me i renamed a folder and for some reason the update didn't push to git

Answer (score 2):

It seems like I have run into the same error.

The strange thing is that I have been building on Vercel all weekend without any problems, and it only started failing after I added Tailwind CSS to my project.

The first build with the Tailwind CSS addition succeded but styling was not loaded.

You can still see the result at https://rolfmadsen.now.sh/.

The local build with "vercel dev" still runs perfectly.

See the repository at https://github.com/rolfmadsen/search

Error from Build logs:

```
22:28:35.104  
Running "npm run build"
22:28:35.287  
> search@0.1.0 build /vercel/6ddf29b8
22:28:35.287  
> next build
22:28:35.328  
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
22:28:35.329  
  throw err;
22:28:35.329  
  ^
22:28:35.329  
Error: Cannot find module '../build/output/log'
22:28:35.329  
Require stack:
22:28:35.329  
- /vercel/6ddf29b8/node_modules/.bin/next
22:28:35.329  
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
22:28:35.329  
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
22:28:35.329  
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
22:28:35.329  
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
22:28:35.329  
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/6ddf29b8/node_modules/.bin/next:2:46)
22:28:35.329  
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
22:28:35.329  
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
22:28:35.329  
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
22:28:35.329  
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
22:28:35.329  
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
22:28:35.329  
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
22:28:35.329  
  requireStack: [ '/vercel/6ddf29b8/node_modules/.bin/next' ]
22:28:35.329  
}
22:28:35.331  
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
22:28:35.331  
npm ERR! errno 1
22:28:35.332  
npm ERR! search@0.1.0 build: `next build`
22:28:35.332  
npm ERR! Exit status 1
22:28:35.332  
npm ERR! 
22:28:35.332  
npm ERR! Failed at the search@0.1.0 build script.
22:28:35.332  
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
22:28:35.336  
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
22:28:35.336  
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2020-06-21T20_28_35_332Z-debug.log
22:28:35.342  
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Comment: NB. I have had .next in the .gitignore file all along.

Answer (score 2):

in my case it looks like something to do with `yarn` and the next dependency i.e. inside `node_modules/next/dist/bin/next` having conflicts information about something.

never quite understand why after using `next` & building our code into production we still have to rely on the (relatively) heavy module `next`.

the whole notion of doing build is supposed so that it becomes independent of the build tools.

Comment: This is the only thing that actually works for me.. But why does NextJS expect the node_modules in a production deployment where we already ran the export command.. This is mind-boggling

Answer (score 2):

If the program runs normally by executing `node_modules/next/dist/bin/next`, you should suspect that the symbolic link of the file is broken.
In my case, it occurred during AWS deployment, and it occurred in the process of compressing the files for deployment.
So, I was able to solve the problem by adding the symlinks option during compression as shown below.

```
zip -r --symlinks xxxx
```

If it is deployed on a server such as AWS, like me, download the actually distributed program and
Check the node_modules/.bin/next file. If the symbolic link is broken, you will need to find and fix the cause of the broken link during the deployment process.

cf) https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14897#

Comment: Hero! This is exactly what was causing the issue in my CI/CD pipeline

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above problems and nothing works.

The problem got solved when I changed the version of next.js. In case, someone is searching for a solution and nothing works...

Answer (score 1):

just use these commands in your GIT

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add --all .
git commit -a -m "Bugs"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a `.gitignore` file, and adding the **.next** folder to it ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried both installing typescript and creating a .gitignore file for the .next folder but hasn't solved the issue sadly.

Comment: @TomWicks Is there a way for you to completely flush your Vercel app, or to delete this one to create another, and see if it changes anything ?

Comment: Updated the error message in the original question. I'll try creating another Vercel app.

Comment: still got the same issue :(

Comment: @TomWicks this might sound stupid, but do you remember doing anything that could have affected the build operation ? (Adding new modules, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

How I resolved the missing module error on Vercel.

1. install the package explicitly so that it is present in your `package.json`
2. then import the supposed missing module into the app and use it.

**For Example (just a scenario)** // lets assume `lodash` is said to be the missing module,

1 Make sure it is present in your package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    // some dependencies ...
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    // some other dependencies ...
},
```

2 Import and use it in your app (usually, I just console.log the import in a non-production env.)

```
import LODASH from 'lodash'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') console.log(LODASH)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the folder in lowercased, then, renamed it in capitalized, updated all the imports, but, for some reason, Github didn't update the folder name when I pushed the changes. I needed to renamed with a different name. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a problem with that specific package, when I looked for it in my package.json and under node_modules i couldn't find it. Even though it was working in local builds somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I added a NODE_ENV="production" environment variable in vercel which hosed everything for me. Once I removed it, things recovered.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete package-lock.json (rm package-lock.json)
2. Delete node_modules (rm -R node_modules)
3. Switch versions of Node, which is easy if you have Node installed via NVM (nvm install 17, nvm use 17)
4. Install dependencies again with new version of node (npm install)

I ran into this issue on a server running node 16.15.0 LTS, On my local machine node v16.12.0, and on another server running node v12.22.10 and it was not giving the error.

Took a look at my dependencies and decided to switch to Node 17.

```
devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.23",
    "@types/react": "17.0.43",
```

After following the steps above and using Node 17 code ran successfully, and no more error.

Answer (score 0):

If node_modules are transferred to server via git as stated in @Joe Haddad's answer. A different strategy for dealing with the issue worked better for me.

On the server, remove all node and next build files carried over to server, re-install and re-build

```
rm -R node_modules && rm -R .next && rm package-lock.json && npm install && npm run build
```

Edit or create .gitignore and add node_modules and .next then do the following.

Clear out cached files in git repo, re-add files respecting .gitignore, commit and push changes back to your local computer.

```
git rm -r --cached ./ && git add ./ && git commit -a -m "Removing ignored files" && git push
```

On local computer to sync up with newly ignored files. Does not affect local work environment and now you can push and pull successfully.

```
git pull
npm install
```

This approach is faster and saves you the trouble of dealing with git stuff on local machine and pushing back to the server.