# Vercel Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations during "npm run build"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

I'm having issues with multiple components like this. Locally on my computer when I run "npm run build", it works fine.

I've been using node version 16 locally and tried 14, 16, and 18 on vercel, but no luck. I've never had this issue before.

[image: error image]

Comment: https://vercel.com/guides/how-do-i-resolve-a-module-not-found-error It's possible this is the problem. You should probably use consistent naming conventions regardless. I prefer following google's standard of all lowercase file/folder names, with different words being seperated by '-'. E.g. input/nav-auth-button/index.tsx.

Comment: @Zack This fixed the issue thank you! I follow a lowercase for folders and camel for file names and I think a while back I made a mistake in naming the folder and then renamed it but forgot about it. Since I didn't have `git config core.ignorecase` set as false, it didn't update on GitHub

Answer (score 9):

this worked for me:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add --all .
git commit -a -m "Versioning untracked files"
git push
```

I found it here: [How to fix Next.js Vercel deployment module not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378045/how-to-fix-next-js-vercel-deployment-module-not-found-error)

check if that works for you

Comment: Thank you, it was a life saver, worked as charm