# Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/stripe/esm/stripe.esm.node.js' imported [..] Did you mean to import stripe/cjs/stripe.cjs.node.js?

Tags: stripe-payments, vercel

hey i deployed my backend on vercel in work fine but i just update my cors config to allow my frontend to make request and my backend give error on vercel

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/stripe/esm/stripe.esm.node.js' imported from /var/task/controller/payments.js
Did you mean to import stripe/cjs/stripe.cjs.node.js?
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:329:11)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:992:10)
at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:936:12)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1178:79)
at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:835:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
RequestId: 8ec50f31-03c4-4183-85a6-3abbb33142e6 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError

it work fine in my machine and actaully i didn't change anything related to this error and you checkout the code in my repo
backend link :https://github.com/amanullah-swe/EcomerceApp-backEnd

i have little bit idea why i get this error it seems the vercel not support the es6 syntax with stripe and stripe also not clarify the whether it has support or not and all the ai tool like chat gpt and bard also has wrong idea about this if you any info related to this pleas help me

i wana solve this errror and deploy my project

Comment: I'm more familiar with the Stripe side than the Vercel side, but it sounds like where you're trying to deploy to is missing a module dependency. I'm not exactly sure how to ensure those are being loaded properly in Vercel. The behavior sounds similar to what is being discussed here, where it runs as expected on your machine but not when deployed, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378045/how-to-fix-next-js-vercel-deployment-module-not-found-error.  Maybe those solutions will help here?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering (ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND) suggests that Node.js can't find the module you're trying to import. This is often due to incorrect import syntax or the module not being installed.

If you're working in a CommonJS environment, you can use require to include the Stripe package, instead of using ES6 import syntax.

I using ES6 and converting to CommonJS resolved the error on vercel.

Comment: i know that but my code base is to big and i used most off the feature of es6, and it can take me to long to convert all of my code in to common js do you any idea of  better platform to deploy my backend with the es6 feature

Comment: Yes you should try out render in case if your code base is too big to convert.