# Uppercase and Lowercase Difference in Git Markdown

Tags: git, github

**Having:**

- In `ReadMe.md`:

```
    1. Visual Studio > File > New Project >
    ![pic001](pics/pic001.png)
```

- And in `/pics` a file named like this (to which I have not paid enough attention):

  `pic001.PNG`

**The problem:**

In Chrome, the picture from `pic001.png` is not going to be displayed, because it is `pic001.PNG` in the `/pics` folder. But, if you change the name of the file from `pic001.PNG` to `pic001.png`, Git is not going to see the difference and will say its favourite:

[image]

**How am I currently solving this?**

What I am doing now is renaming the files to lowercase, then deleting the `/pics` folder completely, then pushing to github without it. Then adding it back and pushing again. Somewhere at this point, github agrees to change the `PNG` to `png` and to display it correctly.

**Question:**

Is there a git command, that would save me the 2-3 commits and deletions and will agree that the `pic001.PNG` is not the same as `pic001.png`?

Comment: @larsks - well, this works as well, but my initial idea was to have it with lowers. Anyway, when a screenshot is taken, in Windows Snipping Tool the `PNG` is always written in uppercase. And as far as I did not always pay attention to it, I am in that vicious circle of 2-3 pushings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688308/5784831?

Comment: @Christoph - 100% duplicate, I have already voted for closing.