# git status shows all files as modified after clone

Tags: git

After cloning https://github.com/Skeeve/SDK_6.3.0 on my Mac and switching to branch 5.19, git status shows all (or at least a lot of) files as modified.

It's not the line endings and also (I think) not the filename case, as there are real differences shown with git diff.

I have no clue how this could happen.

Just tried it in a debian docker container and I do not face the issue.

Maybe someone here has an idea?

Comment: Is your repo clean after you clone?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just double checked.

Comment: If all you did was clone and switch branches, then I assume you don't care about any changes yet. I would try `git reset --hard @` and see what happens. Also just start over and see if it happens a second time. I would also check your status before switching branches to see if it's even related to the branch switch or not. (Guessing not?)

Comment: Hmmm. I just noticed Mac vs Linux, which makes me wonder about filename case. You said "I think" that's not it. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67095620/184546) to see if the files in question have two versions in the repo differing by case only.

Comment: Reset I tried. Didn't work. I doubt it's filename case as there are actual content changes when checking with git diff.

Update: Followed your link, tried it and yes, it seems, you're right. It seems to be a filename issue…

There are files with the same name and different casing. Wonder how to clean up that mess. It's not my software. I forked the repo.

Comment: If it's not your repo, it might be more trouble to fix than it's worth, in which case you might want to only use that repo in the Linux container. Even if you clean it up you'll have conflicts if you ever wish to get updates from the original repo. Or, I think there are settings in Mac to enable filename case sensitivity, but I don't know if you want to enable that just so you can use this repo.

Comment: You can make a mac disk image in which file names are case sensitive, and mount this .dmg file somewhere and use it easily. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59516454/1256452). Should I close this as a duplicate of [How do I change case of the names of multiple files, already committed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59511102/1256452)?

Comment: "Should I close this as a duplicate"? Yes, please.

Comment: You did notice, that the same answer was already given about a week ago? @Daniel Widdis

Comment: I simply saw this in the review queue and added a vote on the same duplicate. The message you see is auto-generated.   You should get an infobox allowing you to accept the closure and Community-bot will finish the closure.  When it's closed, that auto-comment will be auto-deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TTT pointed out, it can have to do with filename case, and in fact it has. I'm closing this issue now. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67095620/184546