# renamed folder not reflecting post git merge

Tags: java, git, github

I am having some issue after I merged the code and the package/folder named are not showing as expected.

**For example:-**
in **master** branch, someone has changed the below package name and pushed the code

```
com.example.mainDirectory => com.example.maindirectory
```

**Folder structure**

```
src > java >main >com>example>mainDirectory  ==> src > java >main >com>example>maindirectory
```

Now in my **local branch** I am trying to **merge the latest code from master**, but the folder stanture for the adobe change is not reflecting, it's still showing `src > java >main >com>example>mainDirectory` instead of `src > java >main >com>example>maindirectory`

How I can resolve this issue ? so that it should sync with the master branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 possible explanations for this:

1. Both paths exist in the repo, differing only by case. You can check if this is the case (pun intended) using [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67095620/184546).
2. Only the new path (with the desired casing) exists *after* the merge, but Git was unable to rewrite those paths, perhaps because they were locked at the time the merge was performed. In this case, make sure your working state is clean, delete the path with the wrong casing, and then `git reset --hard HEAD` to re-check out the new path with the desired casing.

Comment: I dont think both the point you mentioned is the case. 1.- everything is fine in remote branch, even when i did a git pull I also saw the folder name changed to all lowercase in my local master branch.  2. I did switch to my branch in local and did a git merge master which gave me no error/warning also it displayed the message "renamed src > java >main >com>example>mainDirectory ==> src > java >main >com>example>maindirectory" but the folder name was still showing mainDirectory though the java files inside them showing package name as "com.example.maindirectory"

Comment: @Raj looks like you didn't try #2 yet then. After the merge, if you switch to `master` does the directory change to the desired casing?

Comment: @Raj also, when a *directory* is renamed, perhaps all of the files within it need to be repointed as well. Try running the command in #1 against the entire directory to see if anything on your branch is still pointing to the wrong casing. (Maybe you modified some of those files and the merge in `master` isn't touching them, so both directories actually *do* exist in your branch.)

Comment: I misunderstood the point 2, it seems that worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is on Windows. On Linux, case matters for the file system. On Windows it doesn't.
There is a very easy two-step workaround:

- Rename to `src > java >main >com>example>maindirectory2`
- Rename to `src > java >main >com>example>mainDirectory`

The first rename tells both Git and Windows that the directory has renamed. The second rename does the same but gives you the result you want.

Comment: but this will show that I have made the changes, instead of the person who actually made this changes, I want to avoid that. Yes this in windows I guess that's why it's creating issue

Comment: Then ask them to do the rename, properly this time.

Comment: rename is fine and properly pushed in master, but the only problem is when I am merging that into my local, though it's saying renamed src > java >main >com>example>mainDirectory  ==> src > java >main >com>example>maindirectory, but the folder name in my local it's still showing as mainDirectory