# React app deployment to Netlify : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './pages/HomePage' in '/opt/build/repo/src'

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages, netlify

[image: Deplyment Error]

How can I solve this error?

I tried many approaches like using Netlify CLI, linking to git and github but nothing worked.

The app works fine in development mode with no errors but it shows Error:404 page not found on both Netlify and Github Pages

[image: The link of the deployed app]

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution, I changed the folders' names and pushed them into Github but Github didn't change the folders' names, and Netlify is case-sensitive towards nomenclature.

Comment: update git: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541435/4411101

Answer (score 0):

Check your directory names using `gitbash` terminal, as it works like a linux
Netlify/Vercel are linux containers
check the actual case using gitbash and fix the name as per the import
[image]