# Expo publish fails in github actions but works locally

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to automatically publish my app on expo when pushing on the main branch. When I try locally my app gets published correctly, but the build fails on the CI, because it is unable to resolve my components:

```
expo publish --non-interactive --release-channel default
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    EXPO_TOKEN: ***

[16:28:25] › Expo SDK: 44.0.0
[16:28:25] › Release channel: default
[16:28:25] › Workflow: Managed

[16:28:25] Building optimized bundles and generating sourcemaps...
[16:28:27] Starting Metro Bundler
[16:30:13] Unable to resolve module ../../components/form-controls/button from /home/runner/work/my-app/my-app/src/views/authentication/login.tsx: 

None of these files exist:
  * src/components/form-controls/button(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * src/components/form-controls/button/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
> 1 | import { useContext, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
  2 | import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
  3 | import Button from '@components/form-controls/button';
  4 | import Input from '@components/form-controls/input';
[16:30:13] Error: Unable to resolve module ../../components/form-controls/button from /home/runner/work/my-app/my-app/src/views/authentication/login.tsx: 

None of these files exist:
  * src/components/form-controls/button(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * src/components/form-controls/button/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
> 1 | import { useContext, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
  2 | import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
  3 | import Button from '@components/form-controls/button';
  4 | import Input from '@components/form-controls/input';
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/home/runner/work/my-app/vmy-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:211:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/home/runner/work/my-app/my-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:413:43)
    at Object.resolve (/home/runner/work/my-app/my-app/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:317:42)
    at resolve (/home/runner/work/my-app/my-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:629:33)
    at /home/runner/work/my-app/my-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:645:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/home/runner/work/my-app/my-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:644:33)
    at /home/runner/work/my-app/my-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:329:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/runner/work/my-app/my-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:137:24)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I am using expo/expo-github-action@v7, here are the logs of the expo setup step:

```
Run expo/expo-github-action@v7
Installing expo-cli (5.3.2) from cache or with yarn
  Received 23905004 of 23905004 (100.0%), 24.6 MBs/sec
  Cache Size: ~23 MB (23905004 B)
  /usr/bin/tar --use-compress-program zstd -d -xf /home/runner/work/_temp/5d58b0d1-b4da-4201-8eb9-f28763655d2b/cache.tzst -P -C /home/runner/work/vozik-app/vozik-app
  Cache restored successfully
Installing eas-cli (0.51.0) from cache or with yarn
Validating authenticated account
Patching system watchers for the 'ENOSPC' error
```

Here is my babel.config.js file:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
        envName: "APP_ENV",
        moduleName: "@env",
        path: ".env",
        blocklist: null,
        allowlist: null,
        safe: false,
        allowUndefined: true,
        verbose: false
      }],
      ["module-resolver", {
        root: ["./"],
        alias: {
          "@components": "./src/components",
          "@interfaces": "./src/interfaces",
          "@services": "./src/services",
          "@state": "./src/state",
          "@utils": "./src/utils",
          "@views": "./src/views"
        }
      }],
    ]
  };
};
```

I was initially using relative paths to imports these modules, and then tried to use aliases instead, but it did not change anything. The expo SDK is 44.0.0 and expo-cli's version if 5.3.2 (locally and on github actions). Also, the file `src/components/form-controls/button.tsx` does exist, and the path is correct. I would like to understand why the build is working locally, but fails on the CI?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it turns out that some files had different names on github and on my local repository.

Local:

```
├── form-controls
│   ├── input.tsx
│   ├── button.tsx
```

Github:

```
├── form-controls
│   ├── Input.tsx
│   ├── Button.tsx
```

This is because I am working on Windows which has a case-insensitive file system, and at some point I renamed these two files to lowercase the first letter. My CI was running on ubuntu which has a case sensitive file system, so metro was not able to resolve my modules.

To fix it, I ran:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

If you want more information, I recommend checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688308/6625159), or the [git documentation](https://gitirc.eu/git-config.html).