# Code works using "Live Server" but not when deployed via "GitHub Pages"

Tags: javascript, html, css

[How it's being shipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSBwV.jpg)

Any ideas?

There's also a single warning displaying this:

"Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem? You can consider accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CSS`, `Images`, `JS` folders are not named in lower case.

like

```
./images/face3.jpg
```

should be

```
./Images/face3.jpg
```

but I suggest you rename your folders.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't change the folder's name since it basically created a new folder.. I'm still unsure why it wouldn't simply change the folder's name, it completely made a new folder when I tried to rename it... However, I did end up changing the capitalization inside the index file... It worked! Haha, thanks again.

Comment: @525DMG https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688308/8970303