# How to rename folder from lowercase to uppercase in git

Tags: laravel, git

Everytime I execute `composer update`,

```
Class Database\Seeders\Abc\DatabaseSeeder located in D:/Codes/PHP/Chinabing/httpdocs/database/seeders\abc\DatabaseSeeder.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Database\Seeders\Abc\SomeSeeder located in D:/Codes/PHP/Chinabing/httpdocs/database/seeders\abc\SomeSeeder .php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
```

I think this is because the folder name is "abc".

So I want to change

```
D:\web\myproject\database\seeders\abc
```

To

```
D:\web\myproject\database\seeders\Abc
```

I have done

```
git config --global core.ignorecase false
git config --local core.ignorecase false
git config core.ignorecase false
```

and

```
git mv abc Abc
Rename from 'database/seeders/abc' to 'database/seeders/Abc/abc' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

"Abc/abc" ??

I have saw other solutions, all of them talk about file name, not folder name.

Comment: You could try this command
```git mv <old name> <new name>```

Comment: Your underlying file system is case insensitive (NTFS on Windows) so you'd have to go via some other directory name since both `abc` and `Abc` are the same for this file system.

Comment: oh, and I assumed you are using Windows due to the paths you're using. If you're not - let us know what you're actually using

Comment: yes, it's windows. and <abc> <Abc> doesn't work.

Comment: `git mv abc tmp && git mv tmp Abc`

Comment: phd, it works. Why are you so smart~

Comment: I saw that solution in answers many times. https://stackoverflow.com/q/17683458/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rename+case-sensitive

Comment: Oh, I think I saw this post. But it didn't mark as "Answer", so I didn't see the whole content. Can you please Answer this, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename in two stages:

```bash
git mv abc tmp
git mv tmp Abc
```