# Github pages, my images wont show up. My images folder wont update to lower case

Tags: github, github-pages

[image: INDEX.HTML]I recently created a project, but my images are not showing up. During my initial push, I was able to get the images from my index.html to show. However, I learned that Github Pages is case sensitive, so I made everything lowercase. Now, when I push to Github, my images folder name does not update in Github Pages, and all my images do not show up on the deployment. However, everything works perfectly on my localhost. Here are some screenshots of my VS Code and Github repository.

[image: SCRIPT OLD JS]

I tried to change path names, lowercased everything and still for some reason to no avail.

[image]

[image: GH INDEX.HTML]

[image: GH SCRIPTOLD.JS]

Comment: [Please replace the images of text with just the text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) (this applies to _all_ the images).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I commit case-sensitive only filename changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git)