# File rename changes git not recognizing

Tags: git, github

Somehow after pushing a commit to GitHub, some files get automatically renamed. Now, I renamed those files locally again, but git does not recognize those file renames; it's showing 0 changes, and because of that, I'm unable to push the updated changes to GitHub.

Anyone, please help me with this?

Comment: Has the `.gitignore` changed recently to exclude the directory where the files you renamed are?

Comment: I recently migrated to nextjs from CRA, so I only added the .next folder in the .gitignore apart from that, I didn't make any changes to it. Renamed files live inside the pages folder.

Comment: What does `git status` return?

Comment: It was showing "everything is up-to-date", but after using the `git mv` command to rename the files, it started recognizing the renamed files and my issue is resolved now. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I commit case-sensitive only filename changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git)