# Unable to Stage Changes in Git for Specific Files, Getting Consistent Output

Tags: git, git-add

I'm currently facing a persistent issue with staging changes using Git. No matter which commands I try, I keep getting the same output when I check `git status`. The output consistently looks like this:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified: src/components/ChipButton.jsx
modified: src/components/Layout.jsx

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I've ensured that I'm in the correct repository directory, and I've attempted various commands, including `git add -A`, `git add .`, and `git add -u`. However, the changes in the mentioned files (`src/components/ChipButton.jsx` and `src/components/Layout.jsx`) refuse to stage.

I've also verified that these files are not listed in the `.gitignore` file.

Despite referring to online resources and trying different approaches, I've been unable to move past this roadblock. I appreciate your patience and apologize for any confusion in my previous questions where I included images.

Could you kindly provide guidance on how to proceed?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). A GIF is still an image. Please [edit] your question to include the relevant details _as text_.

Comment: What happens if you add those two files explicitly, with `git add src/components/ChipButton.jsx` and `git add src/components/Layout.jsx`? Alternately, what happens if you run `git commit -a`?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: @ti7 I'm currently using Windows 11. @jim-redmond I encountered an issue where things seem normal when I attempt to add items explicitly using these commands:

1. `git add src/components/ChipButton.jsx`
2. `git add src/components/Layout.jsx`

However, when I check the `git status`, it appears that the files are not staged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the project includes files whose names differ only in case, and your local copy of the repository is in a case-insensitive filesystem? In that case git would expect, say `Layout.jsx` and `layout.jsx`, to have distinct contents, but in your repository they would be a single common file (so can't match git's expectation for both). The fix would be to rename the files upstream or clone to a case-sensitive filesystem.

Comment: this seems likely - for example the default Mac filesystem behaves this way

Comment: Absolutely, you're spot on. The issue here was indeed related to filename case-insensitivity. I managed to resolve it by clearing the cache using the command `git rm -r --cached .`, following the solution I found on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541435/18568151). This did the trick and everything is working smoothly now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This issue is indeed related to filename case-insensitivity in Git. If you're encountering a situation where files are not getting staged even after using the `git add` command,

Execute the following command to clear the Git cache while maintaining your working directory and file changes:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

This command removes the entire cache but preserves your local changes.

After running the cache removal command, proceed to add and stage your files as usual using the `git add` command. Finally, commit your staged changes using the `git commit` command.

This process should fix the issue and allow you to properly stage your files. This solution is based on the information provided in the [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541435/18568151) I came across.