git repo has two folder paths that are the same with exception of case. How to fix?
I'm working in an environment where a dozen or more devs have been working in the same repo over the last few years. We have had a couple of cases where in parallel development of feature branches, folder names were created with the same text, but one might have a name like "newFolder" and the other dev's branch would have "NewFolder". git sees these as distinctly different entities while Windows, the OS we are working in, sees these as the same. The problem is really only relevant because our system uses Python for the backend coding, and Python is VERY case sensitive. So calling a function in a script file in the "newFolder" folder when the file is in the "NewFolder" folder causes a fair amount of difficulty.
I'm trying to figure out a way to rename the "duplicate" folder within git's perspective so we don't have issues like we have been having. Is there a way to do this in git (note, I'm not a git expert. I know just enough to do the day to day things, so this is a bit outside my wheelhouse.)?
FYI, yes, since this ugly little issue first arose, we have created naming standard to ward this off in the future. Just wish it had been done sooner.
Thanks in advance!

Do you want to rename one of the folders so that it has a clearly different name, or do you want to merge the two folders into one?

The actual folder names are "MessageHandlers" and "messageHandlers". I want to rename the "MessageHandlers" reference in git to be "messageHandlers". The actual folder in the OS is "messageHandlers" so the other spelling is inaccurate.

Note your last comment doesn't quite answer @JohnGordon's question. If you have some files in both folders, you want the end state to have all the files in messageHandlers? (And then delete the MessageHandlers folder like it never existed? Which, btw, doesn't actually exist in Git either, since only files are stored, not folders.) If this is what you want, then that would be the merge option, not rename.

In that case, it sounds like you actually want to move (using git mv) all of the files in the MessageHandlers folder to the messageHandlers folder, and then remove the MessageHandlers folder.

But a simple git mv will not work, since you may need to merge files? Plus the content of the files in MessageHandlers may need to be updated (if one or more files are importing the incorrectly named MessageHandlers).

I did note that I am not a git expert, just the opposite, so my apologies for the misunderstanding. I suppose your assumption is the correct one. At the end of the day I want all of the files that have "folder references" that contain either "MessageHanders" or "messageHandlers" to reference the "messageHandlers" folder.
I did find the mv command and tried it with the -n option, but obviously used it incorrectly. When using that command, does it have to be executed at the file level, or can it handle the "move" from the /MessageHandlers/ to the /messageHandlers/ paths.

Do the two folders contain any files that have identical names?  If so, this will require actual programming work, not just git surgery.

@MikeA the -n option stands for dry-run and doesn't actually move the files. Also, you don't need to launch git mv for each file. If you use glob patterns, you can target the whole content of the MessagHandlers folder. However, since Windows is case-insensitive, you need to move the files into a temp folder, and then into the right one. git mv MessageHandlers/* my_temp, rename MessageHandlers in messageHandlers, and then git mv my_temp/* messageHandlers. The /* identifies any file or subfolder.

Yes, I understand the -n option. I was trying to see what it would do. What I put in was the following:
git mv -n Zirconia_mfg/ignition/python-script/MessageHandlers Zirconia_mfg/ignition/python-script/messageHandlers
What it denoted as the result if it were run for real was something like:
Renaming Zirconia_mfg/ignition/python-script/MessageHandlers/... to Zirconia_mfg/ignition/python-script/messageHandlers/MessageHandlers/...
The result would not be a simple rename to the lower case version but the upper case version would be added to the lower case folder.

I'm sure that was just me not understanding the command, but I stopped there and being a git dummy thought I'd find help from knowledgeable folks.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+case-sensitive

@MikeA my bad, I thought you were expecting an actual output with the -n option.

I did the following and it worked perfectly.
git mv -v 'Zirconia_MFG\ignition\script-python\MessageHandlers' 'Zirconia_MFG\ignition\script-python\temp'

Once that finished I then ran the command:
git mv -v 'Zirconia_MFG\ignition\script-python\temp' 'Zirconia_MFG\ignition\script-python\messageHandlers'

Thanks for all the input!

The following command should fix things on the git side, to be run in git-bash:
# list all files in "bad" directory, and read their names one by one:
git ls-files MessageHandlers | while read -r file; do
    # build name of the expected path:
    # start with 'the good name', add the file path where you stripped 'the bad name'
    target=messageHandlers/${file#MessageHandlers/}

    # create intermediate directories if needed:
    mkdir -p "$(dirname $target)"

    # move file:
    git mv "$file" "$target"
done

# check the result, and commit if all is good
git status
git commit

