# Naming RESTful paths

Tags: c#, java, web-services

I am creating a web service and I have some questions regarding path names. How do you specify actions on resources in a RESTful webservice?

For example: a Quiz resource. You have normal CRUD actions and you also want to do things with the quiz. Such as generating a new quiz. That is a action. Do you use a path like `/quiz/top5` or `/quiz?type=top5` or what?

I don't understand how you write paths that do actions on a resource when creating a RESTful service.

Comment: I would use `/quiz/generate/123` for id `123`

Comment: i'ld be use `/quiz/{id}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend this ebook from [apigee](http://apigee.com/about): [Web API Design: Crafting Interfaces that Developers Love](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/announcement_new_ebook_on_web_api_design).

Following their advice:

- The number one principle in pragmatic RESTful design is: keep simple
  things simple.
- Keep your base URL simple and intuitive.

> ```
> +------------+-------------------+--------------+----------------------------------------+------------------+
> | Resource   | POST create       | GET read     | PUT update                             | DELETE delete    |
> | /quizzes   | Create a new quiz | List quizs   | Bulk update quizs                      | Delete all quizs |
> | /quizes/12 | Error             | Show Quiz 12 | If exists update Quiz 12, if not Error | Delete Quiz 12   |
> +------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+
> ```

Regarding the top list you want, maybe a solution similar to those they outline in the "Pagination and partial response" section may fit your needs:

`quizzes/top?limit=5`

With this, you can first craft a resource `quizs/top` with a default value (5 or 10 items), and later offer the ability to paginate/change the number of items.

Comment: If you were to follow the guidelines in that ebook and have 2 base URLs. How would you obtain a new quiz that is randomly generated by the server? Is /quizes reserved for listing all quizes ( collection )?

Comment: I am not creating it on the client side, I just want a generated one from the server

Comment: I would go for quizzes/random (BTW, I'm going to edit my post to write quiz plural -quizzes- properly :-)

Comment: But then you would break their advice?

Comment: I think I'm not breaking their advice (at least, in wide sense): first element for a collection (quizzes), second element for a specific element in the collection (random = random quiz just generated). The special thing for that resource is that changes every time you get it from the server (but it's clear when someone reads 'random').

Answer (score 1):

It is what you prefer. I personally like the way the last.fm API works:

http://www.last.fm/api/intro

But if your looking for some nice standards, look at this posts:

[What are the best/common RESTful url verbs and actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256349/what-are-the-best-common-restful-url-verbs-and-actions)

[How to create REST URLs without verbs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619152/how-to-create-rest-urls-without-verbs)

Answer (score 0):

Thats really up to you - RESTful patterns dont dictate naming conventions.

[What are the best/common RESTful url verbs and actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256349/what-are-the-best-common-restful-url-verbs-and-actions) this may help you?

Just make the routes sensible: e.g. quiz/show/{id}, quiz/top/{number} etc...

Edit: Add answer to comment around route action naming, taken from Rails Convention.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Comment: So how do you write paths that trigger a "process" on the resource? I mean like an action, not just CRUD paths?

Comment: In the other answer he says that you should use URLs to specify objects, not actions. Hm...so your example of using "top" specify objects?

Comment: Look it really depends on how you want your application to work... how do you want users to interact with your API?

Comment: Let say there is many different type of quiz such as "random quiz" how would you create the path for that? GET `...`

Comment: so if you wanted to show a quiz called "randomquiz" you would do GET /quizes/randomquiz
If you want to create a "random quiz" you would do a post to /quizes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27876/discussion-between-diagonalbatman-and-luckyluke)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11170376/300886 to a similar question.

In general, you should consider what parts of your API should be available via GET, and which via POST. The resources available via GET should normally be described using nouns, the actions (like perhaps posting an answer to a quiz) should rather be available via POST (or DELETE, maybe) described using a verb, perhaps after a noun - name of the resource the action is taken on.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use **directory like structure** for the REST URLs as explained in [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/) article.

A URL like `/{type}/{operation}/{param1}/{param2}...`

looks more intuitive and maitainable (the param can be passed as classic `?=` if they are too many)

so in your case it can be `/quiz/top/5` or if tomorrow it should be **top 100**, then same can be reused as `/quiz/top/100`

Answer (score 0):

**URLs identify** your objects. **HTTP methods specify the action** (or operation) the server should perform on the object.

For example:

```
/quiz/top5
```

- **HTTP GET**: The client requests to see quiz top5, does this mean create a new one? or does this mean display an existing one? It's up to you (the convention for GET is to request objects without altering the state on the server).
- **HTTP POST**: The client requests to persist changes

Comment: The top5 part would mean to dynamically process a list of the top 5 objects. So that fits the umbrella of identifying objects? Not action?