# Api Url Parts Nomenclature

Tags: api, naming

I have an api like

`http://api.mycompany.com/products/bycategory/{category_id}`

How the ending part `/products/bycategory/{category_id}` is named? If I remove the domain part, how can I name the rest if I put it in web.config, for instance?

URI? I looked at some articles but I was confused. Sometimes the full Url seems to be the URI others the mentioned remaining part.

Thanks.

Comment: "API Endpoint"?

Comment: On wikipedia I found out the remaining part is called path + query - I haven't found one term for the all remaining parts.

Comment: `/products/bycategory/{category_id}` is query

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) is made up of these parts:

- the protocol, e.g., `http://`
- the domain, e.g., `api.mycompany.com`
- the path, e.g., `/products/bycategory/{category_id}`
- possibly a query string, e.g., `?key=value&otherKey=otherValue`

It's up to the server how to interpret the path and query string. A simple web server may just serve the file pointed to by the path. An application server may interpret the path as a query.

The [REST resource naming guide](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/) talks about "resources" which makes sense since first a URL is-a [uniform resource identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) (URI). URIs also use the term "path".

See [this question on REST API naming guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778203/are-there-any-naming-convention-guidelines-for-rest-apis) and its answers, the term used there is "path" as well.

I'd also use "path".